# How does compiler know scope variables

Tags: c#, variables, scope

I want to implement a scope variable like compiler in c# knows where the variable is definition.
I mean, like

```
int a = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
{  
   // Here you can use a variable after instantiating it, "a" can still be used
   int b = 10;
}
// b cannot be used here.
```

I want to do it by xml file. like

```
<block>
   <if> 
      <eq>
         <makevar var='var1'>somevalue</makevar>
         <makevar var='var2'>somevalue</makevar>
      </eq>
    </if>
    <get var ='var1' />
</block>
```

This command `<get var='var1' />` can't be used because it isn't in the scope which it assigned in.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little vague, but as I understand it you want to assign something to b inside the loop and want to be able to read it after the loop. The solution to this is actually quite simple: take the variale b out of the scope of the loop.

```
int a = 5;
int b = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
{  
   // Here you can use a and b, or declare a new variable only existing within this scope
   b = 10;
}

// b is now usable everywhere within the class
```

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I want to implement compiler that supports scope variables.

Answer (score 0):

While traversing the XML you can keep track of scope variables. 'makevar' element would add variable to scope of direct parent. I've added comments in your example to show the idea:

```
<block> <!-- block.scope="" -->
   <if> <!-- if.scope=block.scope=="" -->
      <eq> <!-- eq.scope=if.scope=="" -->
         <!-- makevar.scope=eq.scope=="";eq.scope.add(var1) -->
         <makevar var='var1'>somevalue</makevar> 
         <!-- makevar.scope=eq.scope=="var1";eq.scope.add(var2) -->
         <makevar var='var2'>somevalue</makevar> 
         <get var ='var1'/> <!-- get.scope=eq.scope=="var1,var2" -->
      </eq>
    </if>
    <get var ='var1'/> <!-- get.scope=block.scope=="" -->
</block>
```

In general when entering child - set it's scope to parent's (without changing parent scope). When the element is makevar - add this var to scope of element that contains current makevar.

**EDIT**. Change the example above to show idea more accurately.

Comment: Scope should be maintained by the _compiler/parser_ not the user.

Comment: Yes, the attribute was for clarity only. Suppose that scope is Dictionary<string, object>. When parser traverses to child node C of parent node P it just does (in pseudo code) C.Scope = P.Scope.Copy() (you cannot share same object for children). If it finds makevar, it just adds new variable to appropriate scope - C.Parent.Scope.add(var, val)

Answer (score 0):

*I know I shouldn't have but I had some time to spare ;-)*

Here's a suggestion how it could be solved. It's neither complete not really optimized or safe. It's purpose is to just give you something to start with. Your question was about scope so the following code does scope checking in first place.

How it works? Each each node (element) is represented by a class that provides special functionality for it. Each node but the variable is also a Block that can maintain sub-blocks and its variables. The scope of the variables is being checked during parsing by searching the xml tree if the variable belongs to either self or parent node and is before self.

I've *optimized* your xml a bit.

**Program**:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        var block = new Block(xDoc.Root);
    }

    // These lines will cause an exception because both variables are out of scope.
    // <add arg1='a' arg2='b' />
    // <add arg1='a' arg2='d' />

    static string xml = @"
        <block>
            <var name='a'>2</var>
            <if condition='true'> 
                <var name='b'>3</var>
            </if>
            <var name='c'>2</var>
            <add arg1='a' arg2='a' />
            <add arg1='a' arg2='b' />
            <add arg1='a' arg2='c' />
            <add arg1='a' arg2='d' />
            <var name='d'>4</var>
        </block>";
}
```

**`BlockBase`** && **`Block`**:

```
// Provides common functionality for blocks.
abstract class BlockBase
{
    protected BlockBase()
    {
        Variables = new List<Variable>();
        Blocks = new List<BlockBase>();
    }

    protected BlockBase(XElement xBlock)
        : this()
    {
        // Add variables and blocks.
        foreach (var item in xBlock.Elements())
        {
            AddVariable(Variable.Parse(item));
            AddBlock(IfStatement.Parse(item));
            AddBlock(Addition.Parse(item));
        }
    }

    BlockBase Parent { get; set; }

    // Block variables.
    public List<Variable> Variables { get; set; }

    // Sub-blocks.
    public List<BlockBase> Blocks { get; set; }

    // Adds a variable.
    private void AddVariable(Variable variable)
    {
        if (variable != null)
        {
            Variables.Add(variable);
        }
    }

    // Adds a block.
    private void AddBlock(BlockBase block)
    {
        if (block != null)
        {
            block.Parent = this;
            Blocks.Add(block);
        }
    }

    // Get a variable.
    public Variable GetVariable(string name)
    {
        BlockBase block = this;
        do
        {
            Variable variable = block.Variables.Where(x => x.Name == name).FirstOrDefault();
            if (variable != null)
            {
                return variable;
            }
            block = block.Parent;
        } while (block != null);
        return null;
    }

    // Checks if variable is in scope.
    protected bool IsInScope(XElement xElm, string varName)
    {
        // Traverses the tree and searches for variables in parent blocks and before self
        // so that we don't get variables defined after self.
        var xCurrentElm = xElm;
        do
        {
            var variable = 
                xCurrentElm
                .ElementsBeforeSelf()
                .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "var" && x.Attribute("name").Value == varName)
                .FirstOrDefault();
            if (variable != null) return true;
            xCurrentElm = xCurrentElm.Parent;
        } while (xCurrentElm != null);
        return false;
    }
}

// Block class.
class Block : BlockBase
{
    public Block(XElement xBlock)
        : base(xBlock)
    {

    }
}
```

**`IfStatement`**:

```
// An if-statement.
class IfStatement : BlockBase
{
    private IfStatement(XElement xIf)
        : base(xIf)
    {
        Condition = xIf.Attribute("condition").Value;
    }

    public static IfStatement Parse(XElement xIf)
    {
        if (xIf.Name.LocalName != "if")
        {
            return null;
        }
        return new IfStatement(xIf);
    }

    public string Condition { get; set; }

    // Evaluates the condition.
    public bool Evaluate() { return bool.Parse(Condition); }
}
```

**`Addition`** as something that actually uses the variables:

```
// Addition block.
class Addition : BlockBase
{
    private Addition(XElement xAddition)
    {
        Arg1 = xAddition.Attribute("arg1").Value;
        Arg2 = xAddition.Attribute("arg2").Value;
        if (!IsInScope(xAddition, Arg1))
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Arg1", String.Format("{0} is out of scope.", Arg1));
        }
        if (!IsInScope(xAddition, Arg2))
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Arg2", String.Format("{0} is out of scope.", Arg2));
        }
    }

    public static Addition Parse(XElement xAddition)
    {
        if (xAddition.Name.LocalName != "add")
        {
            return null;
        }
        return new Addition(xAddition);
    }

    public string Arg1 { get; set; }

    public string Arg2 { get; set; }

    public int? Result { get; set; }

    // Evaluates the addition.
    public void Evaluate()
    {
        Variable arg1 = GetVariable(Arg1);
        Variable arg2 = GetVariable(Arg2);
        if (arg1 == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("arg1");
        }
        if (arg2 == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("arg2");
        }
        Result = int.Parse(arg1.Value) + int.Parse(arg2.Value);
    }
}
```

**`Variable`**:

```
// Variable.
class Variable
{
    private Variable(XElement xVariable)
    {
        Name = xVariable.Attribute("name").Value;
        Value = xVariable.Value;
    }

    public static Variable Parse(XElement xVariable)
    {
        if (xVariable.Name.LocalName != "var")
        {
            return null;
        }
        return new Variable(xVariable);
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```